# app works when bluetooth is off, but not when its on before the app opens

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I'm trying to follow androids Bluetooth guide to make a simple app that just displays integers to the screen, but I'm having trouble getting the code from the guide to work correctly. When Bluetooth is off, the app requests permission to allow Bluetooth to be turned on, then it turns it on, and I get "Hello world!". But, If Bluetooth is already on, The program just crashes.

```
package com.example.bluetooth;

import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter; 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Find Bluetooth Adapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (!((BluetoothAdapter) mBluetoothAdapter).isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = ((BluetoothAdapter) mBluetoothAdapter).getBondedDevices();
    // If there are paired devices
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        // Loop through paired devices
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {           
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());                                   
        }       
    }
};

// Register the BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
}//end of onCreate

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Thank you very much, for any and all help I receive. This is what I was trying to follow to write the code http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

I apologize for any bad etiquette, in asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override the OnDestroy() function. inside the function write:

```
unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. how do I pass in mReceiver? this is what I added to it. After onCreate I added 
@Override
public void onDestroy(){super.onDestroy();  unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);}

or did I do that totally wrong? Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Put "BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;" after "private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;" this line will change:final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { ... to mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { .... And also check for mreceiver if null in ondestroy. And you did right but missing.